# Logic with MYSQL query multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, logic

Hello I am a bit rusty with MySql, could someone help me with this problem?

Problem: I have the following tables:

[image][image]

I need to get as a Result: `APINAME`, `DESCRIPTION` and `ENDPOINT` (from `APIS` table) where `USER_ID` (from `subscriptions` table) is = "1234" on `API_ID`, notice that `API_ID` has the same value as `APINAME`.

Hope that was clear enough.
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Your problem is you have the following tables? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to make a selection on multiple tables, should I do something like JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.apiname, a.description, a.endpoint
FROM apis a
INNER JOIN subscriptions b ON b.api_id = a.apiname
WHERE b.user_id = '1234'
```

Answer (score 1):

Rusty is an understatement.  You spent more time making the picture than looking for the solution.

```
  select apiname, description, endpoint
  from apis a, subscriptions s
  where a.apiname = s.api_id
  and s.user_id = 1234
```

Comment: I just made a snapshot of MySql Workbench and I have been looking a lot, but thanks

Comment: I've been getting yelled at for using implicit joins. When I see it used, I feel like passing my disappointment along.